# Actionscript 3 spawn multiple objects

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi im pretty new at actionscript and im trying to make a game that is similar to Heartstone but i have no idea how i should make them spawn next to eachother like in hearthstone. Anyone have any idea how i could do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very simple approach, you can analyse and find the best way to implement the logic you need.

```
  const NUM_ITEMS:uint = 4;
  const PADDING:uint = 1;

  var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
  addChild(container);

  var hearthstone:Sprite;

  for(var i:int = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
  {
      hearthstone = new Sprite();
      hearthstone.graphics.beginFill(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
      hearthstone.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 50, 50, 25);
      hearthstone.graphics.endFill();
      hearthstone.x = (hearthstone.width + PADDING) * i;
      hearthstone.y = 0;
      container.addChild(hearthstone);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually very broad, I think if you are not familiar with Object Oriented Programming you should learn at least the basic principles.

I don't know exactly what you want to do or what amount of code you have already written; but the approach is:

1. Create a class (Card.as)
2. Instantiate it as many time as you need and display them

For example, in flash IDE you can create a movie clip, right-click and click "properties", then "export for actionscript" (I don't know the exact terms since mine is a french version). You just have to type a class name (I recommend it to be the same as the movieclip name, although it is not mandatory; let's call it "Card") and then in your code you can add cards this way:

```
var card:Card = new Card();
addChild(card);
```

Combine it with gPeart's code and adapt it to suit your needs.
Later you can also create a Card.as file to write all the "cards" logic in, like handling the different cards graphics and stats, etc.

There are hundred of ways to write a program like that, but I strongly recommend you to start learning about OOP. Even for small projects, actually. There is ton of resources for it on the internet.

I don't know if I really answered your question, hope this helps a bit.